# Where is the QObject's objectName in CDB in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, debugging, qt5, qt-creator, signals-slots

I frequently find myself debugging signals and slots, which means I'm digging around in the Qt source code. I'm currently struggling to determine the sender of a signal to a Qt class's slot. In my own classes I'd just insert a `auto test = QObject::sender();` line into the slot and debug from there, but I don't have that option for a Qt class's slot.

I've gone digging all around `[d]`, `d_ptr`, `[parent]`, etc in the CDB debug window and simply can't find the sender's objectName or className.

[image: Screenshot of debug window]

Where is it? How do I find it? I can't ever seem to get the Expression evaluator to work in Qt Creator so that's not an option.

Qt version is 5.11.1 and Qt Creator 4.7.0.

Answer (score 3):

There is a checkbox in the settings: `Debugger > Locals & Expressions > Show QObject names if available`. Then, you should see it in the Value column right next to the object.

Or you can look it up in the QObject's data:

[image]

Comment: Strange... I don't see the `extraData` member inside my sender's QObjectData > q_ptr > [QObject] > d_ptr, nor does the object's name show up in the debugger even though I have the box checked. Is there className somewhere?

Comment: Scratch that. I found `extraData` but the `objectName` is apparently blank. Question about class name stands, though. I thought Qt classes had reflection?